# Using variable with Background in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, tdd, cucumber

I'm trying to run a feature file like this:

```
Feature: my feature

Background:
  When I do something
  And I choose from a <list>

Scenario Outline: choice A
  And I click on <something> after the choice A is clicked

Examples:
  | list | something |
  |  a   |   1  |
  |  b   |   2  |
  |  c   |   3  |
```

But what happens is when the second Background step runs, in the step definition, `list` is a String with the value `<list>`, and the first Scenario line `something` is `1`, so can Background not use the variables from Examples? Putting a copy of Examples before Scenario Outline does not work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this.  The background isn't necessarily used with a scenario outline, so it can't know that you will have examples.

Comment: @CarlManaster is right. Just move the line to your Scenario Outline.

Comment: I ran into similar issue today, quite annoying. @CarlManaster AFAIK `Background` is used for all scenarios, including `Scenario Outline`, see https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/#background.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is: no. Background is not a scenario outline. It does not take values from Examples, which is exclusively for the Scenario Outline where it is included.
Let's suposse you have several Scenario Outlines. Each of them should have its own Examples sections and it is not shared between them. Consequently, it is not shared with Background either.
That is why it does not work when you move Examples before Scenario Outline, as you mentioned in your question.